Optimization in doors
I was told that doorhandles are situated away from hinges because that way we can get more torque with less force.
But this also increases the moment of inertia , as more mass is far from hinges ( while density of wood is considerable).
My question is "Is there some sort of optimization of door widths for example a particular ratio of lenth and breath , taking into accout the density and so on and so forth"?

also if consider that there are 2 hinges then the force exerted by them (in pairs) would have no net turing effect ,right?

Go to the hardware store. Buy a knob. Attach it to a door close to the hinge, on the side that the door swings toward. (I.e., on the side where you have to pull to open the door.) Now, stand behind the closed door, and pull on your new knob to open it... Any questions? [It's not just about how hard you have to pull. It's also about where you will be standing when the door swings open, and the path you will have to follow from there to get through the doorway.]

@SolomonSlow I'd say that comment would make a reasonable answer, if you'd care to convert it to an answer.

This isn't the kind of problem you would optimize for the force. Doors are built to fit the space and/or be the same as nearby doors. Solid doors are much heavier than hollow core doors. And yet they are all easy enough to open with similar knob configurations. You want doors that look nice and have knobs near the edge where the latch is.

Assuming you want to open a door, making it rotate of an angle $\overline{\theta}$ with a force $\mathbf{F}$ applied at the handle - at distance $r$ from the hinge - and always orthogonal to the door, let's evaluate the angular acceleration of the door as a function of $r$.
Model. Let's neglect friction, and model:

the door as a rigid body with uniform mass distribution $\rho$, volume $V = A \, d = h \ w \ d$ area (height times width) times thickness, mass $m = \rho  V$
the handle as a point mass of mass $m_{hand}$, placed at $r \in [0,w]$ far from the axis of the hinge.

Governing equation. The component in the axial direction of the angular momentum equation reads
$$\hat{\mathbb{z}} \cdot \left(\dot{\mathbf{\Gamma}}_H + \dot{\mathbf{x}}_H \times \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{M}_H^{ext} \right) \qquad \rightarrow \qquad I_H \ddot{\theta} = M^e_{H,z}$$
where $I_H = I_{H, door} + I_{H, handle} = I_{H, door} + m_{hand} r^2$, and $M_{H,z}^e = F \, r$. For a given geometry, and external force, the acceleration is constant and equal to
$$\ddot{\theta}(t;r) = \frac{F \, r}{I_{H,door} + m_{hand} r^2}$$
Study function $\ddot{\theta}(r)$. Let's study the RHS function to find extreme values for $r \in [0,w]$. First order derivative $\frac{d \alpha}{d r}$ reads
$$\frac{d \alpha}{d r} = \frac{F (I_{H,door} + m_{hand} r^2) - 2 F m_{hand} r^2}{(I_{H,door} + m_{hand} r^2)^2} = \frac{F (I_{H,door} - m_{hand} r^2)}{(I_{H,door} + m_{hand} r^2)^2} \ ,$$
thus a global maximum exists at $r^* = \sqrt{\frac{I_{H,door}}{m_{hand}}}$, if $r^* \in [0,w]$, otherwise the global maximum is at $r^* = w$ (I won't prove it evaluating 2-nd order derivatives; take it as an exercise, if you need), or
$$r^* = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{\frac{I_{H,door}}{m_{hand}}} & , \quad \text{if $\sqrt{\frac{I_{H,door}}{m}} \le w$} \\
w & , \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
From this result, you can see that the optimal solution is not at the largest distance from the hinge only if you have a very heavy handle, s.t. $r^* \le w$.
Let's now put some reasonable number here. Let's say that the mass of a handle is $m_{hand} = 0.5 \ kg$, the mass of the door is $m_{door} = 20 \ kg$, and its width is $w = 1 \ m$, so that $I_{H, door} \approx \dfrac{1}{3} m_{door} w^2 \approx 6.67 \, kg \, m^2$. The term $\sqrt{\frac{I_{H,door}}{m_{hand}}}$ is
$$\sqrt{\frac{I_{H,door}}{m_{hand}}} = 3.65 \gt 1 = w \ ,$$
so $r^* \notin [0,b]$ and the optimal solution is $r^* = w$. With this door, you'd need a handle with mass $m_{hand} > 6.67 \, kg$ to get the optimal solution for $r^* < w = 1 \, m$.
